# Check for a folder, then create a hidden folder in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't get this thing to create this hidden folder for the life of me. It completes without any errors just can't get it to create the folder.

```
 
import os
import ctypes
import subprocess
import urllib
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
```

def check_prep (path, stdout, mkdir):
    path = "C:\Sysprep\sys_prep"
    stdout = os.path.exists(path)
    mkdir = os.makedirs(path)

if stdout ==  "False":
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x02
    mkdir
    ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(mkdir, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)

Comment: You are not calling your function, also the local variables in that function will not be available outside of it.

Answer (score 8):

There are many mistakes in the code you posted:

- `path = "C:\Sysprep\sys_prep"` => `\Sys..` would mean the escape character `\S` followed by `ysprep...`; you should use the other slash : `C:/Sysprep/sys_prep`
- `mkdir = os.makedirs(path)` => `os.makedirs(path)` does not return anything.
- `if stdout ==  "False":` => `"False"` is a string; what you want is a boolean: just write `False` (without the quotes).

This should work:

```
import os
import ctypes


def check_prep(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x02
        ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(path, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)


path = "hello/ji"
check_prep(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi for creating hidden folders you can simply do.

```
import os
os.mkdir(".name_of_folder")
```

Make sure to add "." in front of folder name.